# Does Apple try to renew an IOS subscription past the renewal date?

Tags: ios, auto-renewing

I have an app that supports auto renewal and I am trying to determine if I should should keep checking past a renewal date for the auto renewable subscription if Apple tries to renew it past the date if there is an issue with the transaction failing or some other reason.  If so, how long?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I was not clear on my question.  Sorry.  I have an app that supports auto renewal and I wanted to see about Apple renewing it on my behalf and how long they try if there was a problem with billing the customer.  I will edit my question to make it a bit clearer.  Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a subscriber of your App has opted for auto renewal then Apple will keep renewing his/her a/c till the time the subscriber doesn't opt out from it.

Also till the time the billing method which the subscriber has provided the information is valid.

Regards
Rajeev